# creating EBS volumn from and attaching to the same instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

Is it possible to create a EBS volume from and attach it to the same instance?
will boto be of some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to install the ec2-api tools http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?categoryID=88

then use `ec2-create-volume` and `ec2-attach-volume` commands: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/

I haven't used `boto` for this and don't know if it can, but I have found boto to always make things easier if it can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can even do this from the EC2 console:
- create a snapshot of your volume
- create a new volume of that snapshot
- attach the new volume to your instance
all actions are supported by the console